# When a device connects to a phone's internet hot spot, which device serves as the bluetooth central and peripheral device?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, cbperipheral

When you have devices like raspberry pis or laptops and other devices that are connect to an iPhone that is hosting a hot spot, which device serves as the central and the peripheral device?

I am wondering, because I need to initiate an internet connection for a raspberry pi to the hotspot and only have a script that connects a raspberry pi to an iphone - but I can only do this if I have the iphone's MAC address but I only have the pi's address, and have to decide whether in the iOS application I am producing to serve as the central or peripheral device.

Comment: Are you sure you have this right? Most devices use WiFi to connect to a phone's mobile hot spot.

Comment: iOS allows you to have a personal hotspot connection using Bluetooth or Wifi

Comment: I think you need to update the question with some more details of your script. I would expect that you have already paired the phone and the RPi meaning that the phone's address is listed in `bluetoothctl devices`.

Comment: Bluetooth hotspot uses the [PAN Profile](https://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/15/Bluetooth/PAN-Profile.pdf).  This is not BLE